# How to get rows given multiple values of columns by defining a function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
    Longitude Latitude     TWC
1      130.5    -16.5     6.935
2      131.5    -16.5    13.912
3      132.5    -16.5    13.244
4      133.5    -16.5    15.556
5      134.5    -16.5    21.380
6      135.5    -16.5    22.267
7      136.5    -16.5    17.398
8      137.5    -16.5    18.570
9      138.5    -16.5 32767.000
10     139.5    -16.5 32767.000
11     140.5    -16.5 32767.000
12     130.5    -16.5    12.854
13     131.5    -16.5    18.449
14     132.5    -16.5    21.339
15     133.5    -16.5    26.097
16     134.5    -16.5    31.306
17     135.5    -16.5    28.225
18     136.5    -16.5    25.373
19     137.5    -16.5    29.772
20     138.5    -16.5 32767.000
21     139.5    -16.5 32767.000
22     140.5    -16.5 32767.000
```

I have a dataframe like this (much more longer) and I want to get the same "Longitude" and "Latitude" values and then print these rows.

This code helps me

```
data1 <- data[data$Longitude == '130.5' & data$Latitude =='-16.5',]
  Longitude Latitude    TWC
1      130.5    -16.5  6.935
12     130.5    -16.5 12.854
```

but I am looking for a function where I can easily write these two variables(Longitude,Latitude) to get these rows with "TWC" value.

Comment: What do you want as the input arguments in the function?

Comment: long and lat I presume...?

Comment: I put Longitude and Latitude inputs and the function gives the rows.

Comment: @Therru I posted a solution.  Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write a function with the dataset object ('dat'), the respective columns ('Lat', 'Long') and the values to be compared ('valuelat', 'valueLong'))

```
f1 <- function(dat, Lat, Long, valueLat, valueLong){
          dat[dat[[Lat]]==valueLat & dat[[Long]] == valueLong,]
   }

f1(data, "Latitude", "Longitude",  -16.5, 130.5)
#   Longitude Latitude    TWC
#1      130.5    -16.5  6.935
#12     130.5    -16.5 12.854
```

If we are using the same dataset, then we can remove the 'dat' and column name arguments from the function and inside the function, we can change 'dat' to 'data'.

```
f2 <- function(valueLat, valueLong){
           data[data[["Latitude"]]==valueLat & data[["Longitude"]] == valueLong,]
   }

 f2(-16.5, 130.5)
 #   Longitude Latitude    TWC
 #1      130.5    -16.5  6.935
 #12     130.5    -16.5 12.854
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot! & Is it possible to get these rows by writing f1(130.5, -16.5)?

Comment: @Therru Yes, in that case, you will need to change the 'dat' with 'data' and 'Lat', 'Long' with `"Latitude"`, `"Longitude"`

Comment: @Therru In the `f2` I didn't use `data1`, "Longitude", "Latitude" in the arguments.  Please check the function.